# iPhone Add(+) Button Action?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, master-detail

I've created a Master-Detail Application with Xcode 4.3.

In the Master View I want to show the user an alert when the Add (+) button is pressed?

In which method should I place the code for the alert?

Any help will be apprecciated.

Comment: You have to write in add btn action method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method is already created and bound by the template so just change the `insertNewObject` method like this

```
- (void)insertNewObject:(id)sender
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"This is an alert" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

Comment: Probably here. I'll try it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use following code,

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(addButtonActionName)];
```

It will display `+` button in right top corner of navigation bar.

```
-(void) addButtonActionName {
      // Your code for the Alert view 
}
```

Comment: Thanks. trapper answer worked for me. I don't know why yours doesn't show me the alert?

Comment: @ivan.freire : I have not given you code for the alert but I have shown you where to write alert's code.

Comment: Thanks. I made sure I put the right code for the alert but nothing happens when I press the +.

Answer (score 0):

you should creat an

`-(IBAction)SomeAction{
//display your alert view
}`

dont forget to hook it on IB

Comment: But how come I know when the user has pressed the Add(+) button?

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code for adding **BarButton in Navigation Bar**

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(ShowMyAlert:)];
```

& this is for the **event handling**...

```
- (void)ShowMyAlert:(id)sender
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Test Alert Message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];

}
```